# Python pandas pd.ExcelFile() error: open_workbook_2007_xml() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pickleable'

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlrd

I am trying to read an excel file with multiple sheets through pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd

xls = pd.ExcelFile('my_file.xlsx')
```

Error:

```
~/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py in __init__(self, io, **kwds)
    292             self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=data)
    293         elif isinstance(self._io, compat.string_types):
--> 294             self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(self._io)
    295         else:
    296             raise ValueError('Must explicitly set engine if not passing in')

~/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlrd/__init__.py 
in open_workbook(filename, logfile, verbosity, pickleable, use_mmap, 
file_contents, encoding_override, formatting_info, on_demand, ragged_rows)

TypeError: open_workbook_2007_xml() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pickleable'
```

I am using python version 3.6.2, xlrd 1.1.0 and pandas 0.22.0

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please show us some of the code that caused the error in an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The function you are looking for is `xls = pd.read_excel('my_file.xls')`

Comment: @RobinNemeth, I have the same error for that function.
Also, the reason why I am using pd.ExcelFile is because the excel file has multiple sheets within it, and to be able to parse it, it's recommended that I load the file first through the ExcelFile call.

Answer (score 0):

I find a way around it
The problem is actually because of the format of the excel file.
If it's ".xlsx" then it's going to throw an error, but it works fine by saving it into ".xls" format.

Still does not explain the root of the problem so if someone knows a better answer, please let me know.
Thanks